# Increment in iOS Push Notification incrementing all time, even Zero is set?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am setting 0 application icon badge number, as below as opening app.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

but as server sends increment while app is in background of killed state, it never again starts with ZERO.

Say, if it is 2, than will be 3, than will be 4 on every push. If I open App and set it ZERO, and go back, it shows nothing on iCON, but as server sends, it starts from 5.

In short, it keeps existing counter.

How can I fix this issue. I have iOS 10.1, and Xcode 8.1

Thanks.

Comment: You might be getting application badge number from push notification payload. For example if you have the following payload:

   {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
It will be 9 even if you set the badge zero on app quit.

Comment: totally disagree to you. I am not getting any badge : 9 from server, its increment, another strategy.

Comment: Can you show your push notification payload ?

Comment: You should either have an app side logic which should decrement the badge or your server should sent you updated badge count.

Answer (score 1):

The payload that comes from server already has a badge number that will be setted, so no matter what it was previously. Only badge number that you get in payload matters.

What you need to do is add some custom logic to the place where you call `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` so you can reset server badge count each time you activate the app.

Comment: I am doing it 0 in didFinishLaunch. it shows on main icon, means hides badge, but as it comes from server, it again show same count+1 before 0.

Comment: You are setting local badge number to 0, but **server** don't reset count - in next push you get after local reset you get badgeNumber: count+1 in payload, that's why it's setted directly to count+1. What you need is to reset this counter on server as well as in app.

Comment: server never give count+1, it only says increment, no count, no badge number, its simple increment. I am at home, I will give payload tomorrow from office.